# Express get request host

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am trying to get the request host name on express but on the server it gets 0.0.0.0 or server host name. I am trying this to allow only request that comes from my front page web.

Is there a secure way to get the real one and the user cannot change it?

Comment: "Is there a secure way to get the real one and the user cannot change it?" — No.

Comment: And to get the IP?

Comment: Any http header is fakeable, So, there is no "secure" way to do this.